# Getting respective *args, **kwargs from collection of functions, then filling in the irregular 2d structure with provided 1d arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, functional-programming, list-comprehension, inspect

I have data like this:

```
args, kwargs = (('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), {'goo': 1})
```

And I have functions, inside an object, which want these data as arguments. They are to be provided via a method which has this sort of signature (represented just as `*args`):

```
callFunctions((*args, **kwargs), ...)
```

Or, more explicitly in its structure:

```
callFunctions(((args ...), {kwargs ...}), ...)
```

(I hope it's clear enough what I'm expecting in this method.)

Let's say, for the sake of example, that my two functions are as follows:

```
def func1(foo, bar):
    print foo, bar

def func2(baz, goo=0):
    print baz, goo

funcs = func1, func2    # for iteration
```

With that background, here are the two problems I'm having.

#### Getting the format of `*args`, `**kwargs` for each function

I have been trying to use the `inspect` module to get the argument spec for each function, so that I may 'fill in' the structure with the 1d data in `args` and `kwargs`. I've tried the following:

```
format = [(spec.args, spec.keywords) for spec in (inspect.getargspec(func) for func in funcs)]
```

But I don't understand why the `spec.keywords` always gives me `None` (seems kind of asinine). The default value of any keyword argument will appear in `spec.defaults`, but *I don't know how to associate it with the correct keyword argument.* (It's also frustrating that all of the keyword arguments are put into `spec.args`.)

```
[(['foo', 'bar'], None), (['baz', 'goo'], None)]
```

#### Filling in the structure to be passed to `callFunctions`

Assuming I had the structure anyway, filling that structure in with the original data is tricky: Basically, I want to fill the first tuple of `*args, **kwargs` with the first however-many positional arguments, and the appropriate keyword arguments; then, move on to the next tuple with the next however-many positional arguments and appropriate keyword arguments; and so on. I've tried the following:

```
argues = []
positional_index = 0
format = ((('foo', 'bar'), {}), (('baz',), {'goo': 0}))
for pair in format:
    however_many = len(pair[0])
    argues.append((tuple(args[positional_index:however_many]), dict({(k, kwargs[k]) for k in pair[1]})))
    positional_index += however_many
```

But I get this:

```
[(('foo', 'bar'), {}), ((), {'goo': 1})]
```

*Why don't I get `baz`?*

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question.  If you already have it separated out to `('foo', 'bar'), {}` and `('baz',), {'goo': 0}`, why do you need to do any further processing?  Each of those pairs already is the argument set for one function, so you can just iterate over them and pass each one.

Comment: @BrenBarn For the sake of making the pairing clear, I gave the provided `args` and `kwargs` strings of the same name as the arguments in the two functions, but, they could be anything. For instance, the provided `args, kwargs` at the very beginning of my question could be `((1, 2, 3), {'hello':'world'})`.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Your error there is simpler, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question: The thing is that (in Python 2) there isn't a complete distinction between "keyword" and "positional" arguments as such.  Any argument value can be passed positionally or by keyword.  It's just that if the argument doesn't have a default value, that argument must be supplied --- but it can still be passed by keyword.  (In Python 3 it's possible to have true keyword-only arguments that cannot be passed positionally.)

The way to match up the arguments with their defaults, then, is to realize that the defaults can only apply to the *last* arguments.  So if a function accepts four arguments and has two default argument values, those values must be for the third and fourth arguments, with the first two arguments having no default values.  In common parlance, this is a function with two positional arguments and two keyword arguments (although, as I mentioned, this is only half-accurate, since any argument can always be passed by keyword).  As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) says, the `keywords` part of the result of `getargspec` is not meant to hold the keyword arguments; it holds the name of the keyword **varargs** argument (e.g., `**kwargs`), if there is one.

To see how to match them up, just look at the source code for `inspect.formatargspec`, which does essentially this (I changed it slightly to build a list instead of a string representation):

```
args, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)
result = []
if defaults:
    firstdefault = len(args) - len(defaults)
for i, arg in enumerate(args):
    if defaults and i >= firstdefault:
        result.append((arg, defaults[i - firstdefault]))
    else:
        result.append((arg,))
```

For the second part of your question, the problem is just that you're slicing from `positional_index:however_many` instead of `positional_index:positional_index+however_many`.  Also, your dict/set confusion is because you're using a set comprehension instead of a dict comprehension.  Plus, you don't need that call to `tuple`.  Do it like this:

```
for pair in format:
    however_many = len(pair[0])
    argues.append((args[positional_index:positional_index+however_many], {k: kwargs[k] for k in pair[1]}))
    positional_index += however_many
```

Note, though, that one problem with this is you'll be unable to pass different-valued keyword arguments of the same name to different functions.  If you have `def foo(a, b, c=2)` and `def bar(a, b, c=8)`, you have no way to pass `{'c': 1}` to `foo` and `{'c': 2}` to `bar`, because you're only passing one dict at the beginning, which can only have one `'c'` key.

More generally, if you really want to handle any legal argument set, it won't be as simple as this, because even "positional" arguments can be passed by keyword.  If you have a function like `def foo(a, b, c=3, d=4)`, it's legal to call it with `foo(1, d=8, c=7, b=6)` --- you can pass the keyword arguments out of order, and also pass a value for `b` by keyword, even though it has no default value.  So you can't in general just grab positional arguments based on the number of arguments without default values; you have to actually look at which particular arguments were passed by keyword, and only positionally pass the ones that weren't passed by keyword.  (You could of course just say that your function won't work for this sort of case; it depends how general you want it to be.)

Comment: Thanks for the note on the `dict`/`set` comprehension. I'm trying to grok the rest of it currently. By the way, I'm fine with not casting that slice to a `tuple` so long as I can use the `*` syntax to pass it as `*args` - can I do that?

Comment: @2rs2ts: Yes.  The reason you don't need to call tuple is that it already is a tuple.  When you slice the tuple with `args[...]` you're already getting a tuple.

Comment: Noted about the slice... caffeine deprived oversight there. In response to your most recent edit about different-valued keyword arguments of the same name: I've restricted my code structure to ensure that keyword arguments of the same name *always* refer to something which will have the same value (which makes it easy to re-use the keyword arguments).

Comment: Noodling with your first chunk of code - although I'm capable of repurposing it myself, I'd like to point out that it creates a list of tuples of `(arg, [value])` instead of grouping the relevant ones together a la my expected output, on the off chance you intended otherwise.

Comment: @2rs2ts: I was just showing you how to align the arguments with their defaults, you can adapt it to do whatever you want with that info.

Comment: Got it working. By the way, for funsies, I achieved the goal of the code in the first block in this (admittedly unreadable) list comprehension: `format = [(spec.args[:len(spec.defaults)], {k: v for k, v in zip(spec.args[len(spec.defaults):], spec.defaults)}) if spec.defaults else [(spec.args),{}] for spec in (inspect.getargspec(func) for func in funcs)]`. I may work on fixing keyword args out of order and positional args getting put in the keyword args, since although my code follows that standard, the user input may not match that too well, but otherwise this fixed my problems - thank you!